# Swift: numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAt not being invoked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have been trying to display data from Firebase and display in the tableView. The data is fetched properly but is not displayed. Apart from the code mentioned below, I have already added the dataSource and Delegate for the table and the identifier for the cell.

This is the **HomeTableViewController**

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import Firebase

class HomeTableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    print(artists.count)
    return artists.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
    print("Here")
    let artist = artists[indexPath.row]
    cell.artist = artist
    return cell
}
let artistRef = Database.database().reference().child("Fund")
var artists = [ArtistList]()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    artistRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.artists.removeAll()

        for child in snapshot.children {
            let childSnapshot = child as! DataSnapshot

            let artist = ArtistList(snapshot: childSnapshot)
            print(artist)

            self.artists.insert(artist, at: 0)
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    title = "Artcall"

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 290.0
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}



}
```

The main code for my **HomeTableViewCell** is

```
var artist: ArtistList!{
    didSet
    {
        let dateString:String = String(format: "%@", artist.date as CVarArg)
        labelDate.text = dateString
        labelName.text = artist.name
        labelLocation.text = artist.city

    }
}
```

And the code for my model, **ArtistList** is here

```
class ArtistList
{
var name: String = ""
var city: String = ""
var date: Int64 = 0
let ref: DatabaseReference!

init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    ref = snapshot.ref
    if let value = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
        name = value["artist_name"] as! String
        city = value["perf_location"] as! String
        date = value["target_date"] as! Int64
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Check that when you do `self.tableView.reloadData()`, you are in main thread.

Comment: Is your call to `reloadData` even being made? Put a breakpoint there.

Comment: `I have already added the dataSource and Delegate for the table`: where is your `self.dataSource = self; self.delegate = self`? Or is it not necessary cause you derive from `UITableViewController`? If so then ignore this.

Comment: @Purpose Look at the code. It extends `UITableViewController` so no need to set them.

Comment: @rmaddy I know I know! It just never happened to me before that the dataSource is not called At All and I still wanted to help.

Answer (score 0):

UI updates need to occur on the main thread if they are being called within asynchronous functions, so try putting the tableview reload on the main queue like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)

  artistRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    self.artists.removeAll()

    for child in snapshot.children {
        let childSnapshot = child as! DataSnapshot

        let artist = ArtistList(snapshot: childSnapshot)
        print(artist)

        self.artists.insert(artist, at: 0)
    }

    //Print the artists array to verify it is definitely populated
    print(self.artists)

    //Reload tableview on the main queue
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

  })

}
```

Comment: You don't need to implement `numberOfSections`. It defaults to 1 if you don't.

Comment: Could you please guide me a little more on this?

Comment: @rmaddy thanks you're totally right, changing my answer

Comment: @DhanyaBaid I edited the answer with the entire viewDidAppear method. Let me know if you still have questions/need more clarification.

Comment: @KaylaGalway I did what you asked me to and this is the result I got in the log
[Artcall.ArtistList, Artcall.ArtistList]

Comment: @DhanyaBaid did you set breakpoints in your numberOfRows and cellForRow functions to verify that they are definitely not being called?